# Почему такое страное поведение созданного img?

Tags: javascript

Создаю таким образом картинку:

```
function(file,dataUrl){
  var date = new Date();
  var path =  window.location.host+'/frontend/web/image/page/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/'+file.name;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = path;
  document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img);}
```

Но она не отображается на странице, верней отображается вот так:

[image: нет картинки]

Адрес я проверял картинка есть.

Пытаюсь получить данные по картинке вот таким образом:

```
   $("#forIMG").on('click','img',function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Ничего не получаю, что не так?

Comment: _адрес я проверял картинка есть_ - значит адрес не тот. Посмотри консоль браузера, там должна быть ошибка, что он не смог загрузить картинку по такому-то адресу. Вот именно там и нет.

Comment: console.log(path); сделай 
скорее всего хрень с путем

Comment: @Grundy    если адрес указаный в src введу в адресную строку браузера картинка отобразится

Comment: @FrankSinatra я только что ответил но даже это не дает ответ почему второй код не работает.

Comment: сделай просто log($("#forIMG")) и все
не нужно по клику или еще что-то, оно тебе и так покажет обьект

Comment: тогда добавляй скриншоты: какой урл в src, какой ты проверял, ошибку в консоли браузера, возможно что-то еще понадобится

Comment: @FrankSinatra   Вообще клик по объекту #forIMG img не работает

Comment: @Grundy Вот сейчас вообще не понял.

Comment: Просто убери эту странную строку  $("#forIMG").on('click','img',function () и напиши вот так  $("#forIMG").on('click',function (), ты и так посмотришь обьект, а то придумал какой-то img

Comment: @Sergalas, какое из слов: _добавляй скриншоты_ - непонятно?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`window.location.host` не содержит в себе протокол
Например, `window.location.host` на текущем сайте - это `http://ru.stackoverflow.com`
Не получится загрузить картинку к примеру с `http://ru.stackoverflow.com /image/image.png`, нужно указать протокол, по которому должна происходить загрузка лучше было в пути вообще не указывать `window.location.host`

Comment: Идея-то верная, но написано неверно...

Comment: А зачем нужен вообще window.location.host ? если картинке задать  путь, начиная с `/`, то по умолчанию пойдет обращение именно на текущий хост

Comment: @Mike ну вот она где собака порылась я же спрашивал почему такая ошибка

Comment: @Qwertiy а что не верно?

Comment: Как минимум, пример. А дальше вообще как-то мутно написано.